# Upload file with name not extention can't save name of file cake php 2.5.5

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.5

Upload file with name not extension can't save name of file. I am using CakePHP 2.5.5 and I have a problem with uploading files "name   of file " I don't have error but the name of file don't save in database, but with save extension file all be good. My code:-

```
public function ajouter()

    {//verifier si la requete est de type post
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {

            $this->Activite->create(); 
            //debug($this->request->data);die();

            if ($this->Activite->save($this->request->data)) {

                $path=$this->request->data['Activite']['actv_file']['name'];

                $filename=strToLower(pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_BASENAME));

    if(!empty($this->request->data['Activite']['actv_file']['tmp_name']) && in_array($filename,array('docx','pdf')))               
                 {

                     move_uploaded_file(
                    $this->data['Activite']['actv_file']['tmp_name'],
                    'files'.DS.'.'.$filename);

                    $this->Activite->saveField('file',$filename);

                $this->Session->setFlash('Ajout bien succé.'); // methode du component flash pour définir un message dans une variable session 

                $this->redirect('index');
                 }


             }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the correct filename with `debug($filename);die();` after:

```
$filename=strToLower(pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_BASENAME));
```

?

In all php versions I've used the correct usage is actually:

```
strtolower();
```

Notice that the entire method name is lower case. If PHP doesn't recognize the method it is probably setting `$filename` to `NULL`?

Also I noticed your in_array() method is looking for a file extension yet $filename will contain the base name `pathinfo($path,PATHINFO_BASENAME);`

If you ever want to enter your if statement you need to add

```
$fileExtension = pathinfo($path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
```

and replace:

```
in_array($filename, array('docx', 'ppt'));
```

with:

```
in_array($fileExtension, array('docx', 'ppt'));
```

Comment: with debug($filename);die();  show me name of file , also i change function to strtolower(); but the same problem name of file not save to data base !but with extention all good !!!

Comment: add these lines just **before** you call `$this->Activite->saveField('file',$filename);` and post results.

`debug($this->Activite->id);`
`debug($filename);`
`exit;`

Also please can you tell us your table field names?

Comment: @drmonkeyninja Thanks for the format fixing.  Im new haha. Now I get how it should be done, thanks!